# ItemCollection does not contain a definition for FindByText

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having trouble with the following if statement:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    String Name = dr.GetString(1);

    //if (cbPart.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(f => f.Text).Contains(Name))

    if (cbPart.Items.FindByText(Name) != null)
    {
        cbPart.Items.Add(Name);
    }
}
```

Why is it saying that `FindByText` is not contained in ItemCollection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it is an [ItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx) in *System.Windows.Controls* not a [ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx) in *System.Web.UI.WebControls*.

Comment: So what is the alternative to findbytext